Two ways to add Cloudflare web analytics to Cloudflare Pages: which one?
I made a static website with Cloudflare Pages and a custom domain, so I tried their free web analytics. I found two ways to add analytics:

Directly from Pages, ie Pages > Manage > Web Analytics > Activate. With this method, the Javascript snippet is automatically added to the website on the next deploy.
From Analytics & Logs > Web Analytics > Add a site. As I use a custom domain which is proxied through Cloudflare, with this method I can activate analytics without Javascript.

If both methods work, what would be the preference?
I accidentally activated analytics with both methods on the same domain and I have kept them for now, but when I visit the page, the visit does not appear. I tried with different browsers from different IPs, with and without VPN, but I couldn't get it to log the visit.
Is there something I should be aware of to make web analytics work?
